# How do I cast an object of a class created at runtime to an object of a class created at build time?

Tags: c#

I need to repeatedly compile a specific class while a program is still using it. In order to do this I cast an object of the new type to an object of the old type. I have a small example below:

```cs
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

namespace Test {
    internal class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            object oldInst = new Tester();
            object newInst = new CSharpCodeProvider()
                .CompileAssemblyFromFile(
                    new CompilerParameters {
                        ReferencedAssemblies = { typeof(Program).Assembly.Location }
                    },
                    "Tester.cs"
                )
                .CompiledAssembly
                .CreateInstance("Test.Tester");
            // Perfectly fine
            Tester firstCast = (Tester) oldInst;
            // Throws "System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid."
            Tester secondCast = (Tester) newInst;
        }
    }
}
```

This is `Tester`'s source, it is in `Tester.cs`:

```cs
namespace Test {
    public class Tester { }
}
```

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18083740/8003621) about interfaces is similar to mine, except that in my actual code it already depended on the assembly the original class is defined in so that isn't a solution.

EDIT: I need to do this because I already load the class in the game, then edit the file, and need to create a new instance of the class that already exists. I do understand that they are not the same class, as Amy's answer pointed out. Further, I can't modify any of the methods that use the original class because I can't edit that part of the game, this is for a mod.

Comment: "I need to repeatedly compile a specific class while a program is still using it."  This sounds unusual.  Why do you need to do this?  Your question sounds like an [X/Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: The reason I need to recompile it to load the compiled code into the program while it's running. In my actual problem, I'm trying to reload a GUI's class from disk and update what is in the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Tester` class compiled into your application, and instantiated on line 1 of `Main`, is *not* the same class as `Tester` that is compiled into the dynamic assembly.  So the cast fails.

You can demonstrate this by:

```
Console.WriteLine(oldInst.GetType() == newInst.GetType());
```

Type `A` from assembly 1 is not the same type as `A` from assembly 2, even if they share the same name and contain the same properties, fields, and methods.  They both look like a duck, and they both quack like a duck, but they aren't the same kind of duck.

You won't be able to do a cast to the dynamically-compiled type.  To access members of that type, you must use reflection.

An alternative is to use an interface from a reference assembly, and have both the "real" `Tester` and the dynamically-compiled `Tester` both inherit from that interface, in that assembly.  You would then be able to cast to the interface.

Comment: This is very close to perfect, but I doubt it's possible to get the complete compatibility I originally wanted. Luckily, in the actual code, it was good enough to up cast the object and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.` is becouse you want to cast other assembly class as yours assembly cast. You should use reflection to use `secondCast` methods. If you want use it in your code, you must do one of following things:

1. Use interface in yours code or in some class project, and `secondCast` should inherit it
2. Make `secondCast`'s class as child class of `Tester` in yours assembly - in this way your cast to `Tester` should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dynamic` keyword to achieve what you want.
Let's add a method to Tester so that we can demonstrate how to use it.

```
// Tester.cs
namespace Test
{
    public class Tester  {
    
        public string DoSomething()
        {
            return "I am a tester";
        }
    }
}



// Program.cs
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

namespace Test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object oldInst = new Tester();
            object newInst = new CSharpCodeProvider()
                .CompileAssemblyFromFile(
                    new CompilerParameters
                    {
                        ReferencedAssemblies = { typeof(Program).Assembly.Location }
                    },
                    "Tester.cs"
                )
                .CompiledAssembly
                .CreateInstance("Test.Tester");

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", DoSomethingWithTester(oldInst));// prints "I am a tester"
            
            dynamic dynInst = newInst;

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", DoSomethingWithTester(dynInst));// prints "I am a tester"

        }

        public static string DoSomethingWithTester(dynamic tester)
        {
            return tester.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```